# CSV download using wget

Tags: python, shell, wget

I need to download the csv files after clicking I agree from the below page -

http://www.gasbb.com.au/

click on Region SA
click on I agree

Links on left hand side of the page
Forecast Pipeline Flows 
Capacity Outlook

Can you please let me know if this can be done using wget?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. All you need to do is to find out where the resource's public url is using your browser's developer console (or firebug).

In this case, I have located it for you. So:-

```
wget http://www.gasbb.com.au/Data/Public/E_AUST/int923_v1_forecast_pipeline_flow_r_1~20121122000650.csv
```

Reference my chrome's developer console:-

[image]

Comment: I need to automate this download everyday. CSV file name includes time. But we do not know the exact time the files are posted. If I knew the time, I could have constructed the URL. Can I specify some regular expression in wget to achieve this?